# Choosing a $c$ and $n_0$ that shows that $f(n) \in O(g(n))$ or $\Omega(g(n))$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

How do you accurately select a $c$ or $n_0$ value that would effectively prove these cases?

For example, if you had $f(n) = log_3(n)$ and $g(n) = log_9(n)$, how would you know to select $c = 1$ and $n_0 = 2$ to prove that $f(n) \in O(g(n)$?

Similarly, if you had $f(n) = 3n+n log(n)$  and $g(n) = (5 log(n))$, how would you know to select $c = 1$ and $n_0 = 2$ to prove that $f(n) \in \Omega(g(n)$?

From the way that I have seen such proofs demonstrated, you are meant to select $c$ and $n_0$ first before beginning your proof, and then retroactively prove that those values satisfy the definitions of $O(n)$ and $\Omega(n)$.

It is not clear to me how to accurately and effectively select these values without randomly guessing.

Comment: In the first question, $f(n) = \frac{\ln n}{\ln 3}$ and $g(n) = \frac{\ln n}{\ln 9}$, so the ratio $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \frac{\ln 9}{\ln 3} = 2$, which is why such a constant works. There is no more general procedure than to sit down with the functions themselves and work out the ratio between them.

Comment: Is the work done to find $c$ and $n_0$ typically intended to be implied in these proofs? In solutions that I have found, they typically begin with a statement like "Assume $c = 7/5$ and $n_0 = 3$" as if it was chosen as a random guess.

Comment: From one perspective, proofs aren't meant to illustrate the reasoning used to arrive at the proof. They are only meant to demonstrate truth. So starting a proof with numbers that "just work", without further explanation, is sufficient. But for educational purposes a student may find it lacking.